# React invoke Ajax request on select chage

Tags: reactjs

I am having a select box, and need to invoke ajax request to bring new data from the server.

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        'dayFilter': "last_day"
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getCurrentCampaign();
};

// get current channels
getCurrentCampaign(){
  client.get('channels', {params: {day_filter: this.state.dayFilter}}).then(res =>{
    this.setState({
      oCurrentCampaign: res.data
    });
  })
};

selectDayFilter(selectedSelect){
  this.setState({'dayFilter': selectedSelect.value});
};


render(){
    return (
        <div className="_dashboard ng-enter ui-view">
            <div className="section">
                <h2>Current Channels</h2>
                <Select value={this.state.dayFilter} className="se_type1" name="form-field-name" searchable={false} options={options}
                onChange={this.selectDayFilter.bind(this)}/>
                <CurrentCampaign oCurrentCampaign={oCurrentCampaign}/>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

selectDayFilter gets invoked whenever user selects different option from the select and then state is getting set

```
  this.setState({'dayFilter': selectedSelect.value});
```

What's the best way to invoke `getCurrentCampaign`, so filtered data can be pulled from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to fetch the data every time the select change. I guess you can pass your getCurrentCampaign as a call back to This.setState. Like:

```
this.setState({'dayFilter': selectedSelect.value}, this.getCurrentCampaign);
```

Alternatively you can put it inside component will update and check if the dayFilter has changed in next state.

But I am not sure which approach is the best one. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

My suggested flow should be like this:

A user types somethings and then onChange trigger selectDayFilter function

```
//Pseudocode 
selectDayFilter(
 setState "dayFilter"
 call getCurrentCampaign // ajax request
)

getCurrentCampaign(){
 if ajax.success{
 setstate "oCurrentCampaign" // it will trigger re-vender
 }
}
```

hope it helps